# Row reduction with 2 identical rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I started out with this matrix :

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 6 & -2 & x \\
3 & 0 & 1 & y \\
4 & 6 & -1 & z
\end{pmatrix}$$
When I do the operations $R_2 = -3R_1 + R_2$ and then $R_3 = -4R_1 + R_3$, I get the following.
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 6 & -2 & x \\ 0 & -18 & 7 & -3x + y \\ 0 & -18 & 7 & z -4x
\end{pmatrix}$$
I noticed that $2$ rows are the same. I am not sure where to go from here. I need to keep reducing I think. I am looking for the span.

My Question is : What happens with identical rows?? And What is the span?

Thanks

Comment: Subtract one row from the other to the zero row.

Comment: Those rows *aren’t* the same.

Answer (score 0):

By subtracting the second row from the third one we obtain 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 6 & -2 & x \\ 0 & -18 & 7 & -3x + y \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & z -x-y
\end{pmatrix}$$
Hence we have that the rank is $2$ if $z=x+y$ (i.e. if the second and third rows are equal).

Otherwise the rank is 3.

Comment: thanks What would be the span if [x, y , x+y]?

Comment: What is $ [x, y , x+y]$? Is the initial fourth column?

Comment: I am not really sure what I am doing to find the span. I thought you just substittue z with x + y into the [x, y, z] span.

Comment: If $z=x+y$ then the vector space generated by the 4 column vectors has dimension $2$ and a base is for example $[1,0,1]^t$ and $[x,y.x+y]^t$.